# How can I make the length of all the vectors in a vector plot equal?

Tags: plotting

I tried

```
(*1.3 #13*)
VectorPlot[{1, 1 - 2*y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  StreamPoints -> 100, StreamStyle -> Red, 
  VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0], VectorScale -> None]
```

But I get

> VectorPlot::vectsc: None is not a valid VectorScale specification.

[image: Vector Image]

The plot has unequal vector lengths. What can be done instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is a bit different:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1 - 2*y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, StreamPoints -> 100, 
 StreamStyle -> Red, VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0], 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}]
```

gives the desired result (see documentation of VecotrScale/examples)